# Why "did" and not "had done"?

Tags: past-tense

> He had relocated the same day as I **did** after switching university. We kept in touch regularly.

Why **did** and not **had done** if both relocated the same day, same tense should be used?

Comment: There could be in the wider context some other event against which his relocation is set.  Looking at a sentence in isolation is not a good way to determine the reason for a particular tense choice.

Answer (score 3):

"Had done" is more correct in the context, but in casual English we often substitute the simpler past tense for the past perfect unless it's really important to keep an order-of-events clear.

I agree that in this case, the author should have used the same tense for both verbs; it does read a little strangely.

Comment: I don't think it reads strangely at all. It depends on the context. It's the kind of tense structure that one would use naturally, for example, when talking about a friend who had died. **Had relocated** would be appropriate in view of his death - and the past tense for the speaker who is reflecting on what **he did**.

Comment: It reads strangely because of the verb disagreement.  "He relocated the same day as I did" or "he had relocated the same day as I had" would both read fine, but the mix'n'match verb tenses are weird.

Comment: the problem with your interpretation is that none of the character in the story are dead or will be dead